# How to edit a Grafana dashboard which keeps freezing due to a bad query

Tags: grafana

I have a Grafana dashboard to which I have unfortunately added a graph which freezes the browser tab due to the large number of time series it tries to load. I am unable to edit it as the dashboard freezes within seconds of loading, rendering the entire dashboard unusable.

Is there a way to open a Grafana dashboard in some sort of "safe mode" where it will not attempt to pull data or render the panels, so that bad queries like these can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get around it by appending the parameter `var-something=blah` to the dashboard URL, where `$something` was a dashboard variable. Doing the above caused the page to load with the bad query broken.

Comment: We had this problem, so it's good to know how to do this. We ended up rewriting our plugin using D3 to paint the graph on a canvas, not SVG as this was overloading the browser. BTW, make sure to accept your own answer :)

Comment: Another approach might be using grafana HTTP API ( http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/dashboard/): get broken dashboard, edit json data, delete old dashboard, add new(edited) one.